# What instruments or sounds do most composers start a song with?

Tags: music

I found myself to mostly start with drum[s] when I was younger, and  progressing into other instruments, until eventually being able to create based on nothing more than a snippet of anything I hear.

Comment: I'm sure there are as many ways to compose as there are composers.

Comment: I'm unlikely to start with guitar if I'm doing an orchestral film piece & equally unlikely to pick flute for a metal track...